# Query a date between today's date and the coming 6 months

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query my database to get all infrastructures with a due date (inf_lifespan) is between 6 months away from today's date.

```
inf_lifespan
2028-09-19
2025-12-04
2020-11-11
2026-02-17
2019-12-12
2020-11-13
2018-12-13
```

Running this query will generate no record but I expect that infrastructure with a due date of 2018-12-13 should be the outcome of the query.

```
select * 
from tbl_infrastructure 
where `inf_lifespan` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 0 MONTH )
```

I m using 5.7.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Can anyone help me with this, please

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `date_sub` in standard SQL and those dreaded backticks are also invalid in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the condition  `BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 0 MONTH )`

you will the date from 6 months ago to today.

You can try to use [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) instead of `DATE_SUB`, because of `DATE_SUB` function is sub the month.

```
select * 
from tbl_infrastructure 
where `inf_lifespan` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```